# Is there a limit on the chaining of nodes in the shader editor?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, bump

I'm trying to create a procedural texture in cycles using smaller texture maps with masks separating them. Each texture map is grouped with a mask and image texture. It is then outputted into a mix RGB node  in add mode with a factor of 1 combining both groups. The process is repeated 18 times. The setup went as expected until I reached the 7th node setup. When I go beyond the 7th node and plug it into either the add RGB or bump map socket, the entire mesh rendered black as if there no material on it. If I connected all the nodes and view them in preview mode with the node wrangler all the textures will appear as expected. Here's a preview of my setup.

[image: Inside of the texture node]

Inside the texture node.

[image]

Node chaining on the outside. (same results occurred regardless of adding the images together directly or through the bump map.)

I want to know if is this a shading issue due solely to the node setup or is there a limit on how many node chains can blender handle?

Comment: The limit is based on your Graphics Card Memory... You probably reach the SVM Stack Limit

Comment: What's an SVM stack limit and can it quantified?